# Replace text between two special characters

Tags: regex, r, text, replace

I have a character vector as:

```
x<- "\t\t<taxon id=\"TOT_F50\"/>"
```

and

```
 y<- "TOT_A01"
```

and I want replace `TOT_F50` with the text in y ("TOT_A01").

Do you know how to replace the text between " and \ (i.e. "TOT_F50) ?

Comment: sorry, i did an error typing AMBO at the place of TOT.

Comment: And if for example I would like to replace a text after three tabs in a string? Do you know if there is some guidelines about "how manage this syntax..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 sub('(?<=").*(?=")', y, x, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "\t\t<taxon id=\"TOT_A01\"/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
gsub("\".*\"", paste0("\"", y, "\""), x)
```

It just means "find text within two quotation marks in `x` and replace it with `y` inside two quotation marks"

I think this is what you want, your example is wrong though